# How to clear previous DBContext DbEntityValidationException error before resubmit

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, dbcontext

I have a simple form to add an object named "ActionItem" to database. The simplified code is like following:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ActionItem(ActionItem model)
{
   try
   {
       string error = string.Empty;
       actionItemRepository.DBContext.ActionItems.Add(model);
       actionItemRepository.DBContext.SaveChanges();
   }
   catch (DbEntityValidationException dbEx)
   {
       DbValidationError dbError = dbEx.EntityValidationErrors.First().ValidationErrors.First();
       error = dbError.PropertyName + ": " + dbError.ErrorMessage;
       return null;
   }
   catch(Exception ex) {....}
   return View(some updated obj);
 }


public partial class ActionItem
{
    public long AIID { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime DueDay { get; set; }
    public Nullable<long> EntityID { get; set; }
    public int EntityType { get; set; }
    public int TotalProgress { get; set; }
    public int CurrentProgress { get; set; }
    public int Status { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Note { get; set; }
    public Nullable<long> SeriesID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> SeriesCount { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Priority { get; set; }

    public virtual ActionSeries ActionSeries { get; set; }
}
```

Since I forgot to check the name of the actionItem object needs to have no more than 50 characters, the SaveChanges() throw an DbEntityValidationException, which is cool. But when I fixed it on UI and submit the correct name, I can trace and confirm the name is shorter before SaveChanges(), but the same exception is thrown again. It seems like it always remember the previous error and doesn't want to reset. Is there a way to clear previous errors of DBContext?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi, please post the relevant part of `ActionItem` and the way you are creating the `DbContext` in your repository. You should have a fresh context on a resubmit.

Comment: Thanks Stefan. I've posted the ActionItem class. It's very simple. I just don't know how to "refresh" the context on resubmit. I cannot find any method...

Comment: Short answer: dispose DbContext as soon as possible. Use separate context for each web request or even for each single repository operation. Details: http://mehdi.me/ambient-dbcontext-in-ef6/

Answer (score 0):

Use `ModelState.Clear();`
This will clear previous errors